# apiplatform - react admin: token in localstorage null on redirect, have to refresh page

Tags: authentication, jwt, local-storage, react-admin, api-platform.com

I'm using the stack apiplatform and react admin.
My JWT authentification works fine on apiplatform.

I try to use it on my react admin backoffice.
I followed those documentations:

- https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/authentication-support/
- https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Authentication.html

The authentification/authorization works but on login success, I am redirected to the backoffice and I have a server communication error because the token send to the api is null.

I see it in the localstorage and **if I refresh the page, everything works fine.**

It's like the redirection on success happen before the token was store.

Here is my code:

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { HydraAdmin, ResourceGuesser } from "@api-platform/admin";
import authProvider from "./components/authProvider";
import parseHydraDocumentation from "@api-platform/api-doc-parser/lib/hydra/parseHydraDocumentation";
import {
  dataProvider as baseDataProvider,
  fetchHydra as baseFetchHydra
} from "@api-platform/admin";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const entrypoint = "http://localhost:8089/api";
const fetchHeaders = {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem("token")}`
};
const fetchHydra = (url, options = {}) =>
  baseFetchHydra(url, {
    ...options,
    headers: new Headers(fetchHeaders)
  });
const apiDocumentationParser = entrypoint =>
  parseHydraDocumentation(entrypoint, {
    headers: new Headers(fetchHeaders)
  }).then(
    ({ api }) => ({ api }),
    result => {
      switch (result.status) {
        case 401:
          return Promise.resolve({
            api: result.api,
            customRoutes: [
              {
                props: {
                  path: "/",
                  render: () => <Redirect to={`/login`} />
                }
              }
            ]
          });

        default:
          return Promise.reject(result);
      }
    }
  );
const dataProvider = baseDataProvider(
  entrypoint,
  fetchHydra,
  apiDocumentationParser
);

export default () => (
  <HydraAdmin
    apiDocumentationParser={apiDocumentationParser}
    dataProvider={dataProvider}
    authProvider={authProvider}
    entrypoint={entrypoint}
  >
    <ResourceGuesser name="resource" />
  </HydraAdmin>
);
```

authProvider.js

```
import { AUTH_LOGIN, AUTH_LOGOUT, AUTH_CHECK, AUTH_ERROR } from "react-admin";

export default (type, params) => {
  if (type === AUTH_LOGIN) {
    const { email, password } = params;
    const request = new Request("http://localhost:8089/api/login_check", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
      headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })
    });
    return fetch(request)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
          throw new Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(({ token }) => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", token);
      });
  }
  if (type === AUTH_LOGOUT) {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  if (type === AUTH_ERROR) {
    console.log("AUTH_ERROR");
    //localStorage.removeItem("token");
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  if (type === AUTH_CHECK) {
    return localStorage.getItem("token")
      ? Promise.resolve()
      : Promise.reject({ redirectTo: "/login" });
  }
  return Promise.resolve();
};
```

Comment: How was this solved?

Comment: It was not, I did not find any solution and no one answer to me.
I think, it's a problem with the HydraAdmin component but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the right solution because like you, I didn't find anything about this problem.

But for me, if I just call `window.location.reload();` after `localStorage.setItem('token', token);` it solves the problem for me, because after login, it reloads admin and at that moment, it can recognize token. Maybe it's not the cleanest solution ever but it works well.

By the way, I think, this is not a problem related with the HydraAdmin component, I tried the classic React Admin component and the problem is still there, so it's related to React Admin.